# Asp.net jquery reqex conversion?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, regex

Is there an easy way to do the equivalent in jquery or jscript for that matter.

```
NewString = Regex.Replace(SOMESTRING, "[^a-z0-9A-Z -]")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
newString = someString.replace(/[^a-z0-9A-Z -]/g, "");
```

Without the `g` (**G**lobal) flag,it will only replace the first match.

Answer (score 0):

```
NewString = SOMESTRING.replace(/[^a-z0-9A-Z -]/g, "new string")
```

But what you wrote isn't actually a valid static method of Regex.

Comment: **You need to assign the return value** – Strings are immutable.

Comment: @SLaks: I'm not that dumb, just didn't translate the entire line, edited. Although I did steal the /g from you, thanks.

Comment: Yes; you and I realize that. However, Joe Programmer might not.